# How to re-group an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this set of array in my javascript.

```
var array = [
['Jack', 'A'], 
['Jack', 'A'], 
['Sara', 'A'], 
['Jack', 'B'], 
['Peter', 'B'],
['Sara', 'C'], 
['Sara', 'B'],
['Sara', 'A'],
['Sara', 'B'], 
['Peter', 'B'],
['Peter', 'A'],
['Peter', 'C']
];
```

my goal is to be arranged like this as an array.

```
Jack: A : 2
Jack: B : 1
Sara: A : 2
Sara: B : 2
Sara: C : 1
Peter: A : 1
Peter: B : 2
Peter: C : 1
```

I am trying to code it like this but I can't get it right

```
let counts = {};
array.forEach(element => {
     counts[element] = (counts[element] || 0) + 1;
});
```

does anyone has an idea about this one?
Thank you..

Comment: Is the expected result an array? Please specify it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
let array = [
        ['Jack', 'A'], 
        ['Jack', 'A'], 
        ['Sara', 'A'], 
        ['Jack', 'B'], 
        ['Peter', 'B'],
        ['Sara', 'C'], 
        ['Sara', 'B'],
        ['Sara', 'A'],
        ['Sara', 'B'], 
        ['Peter', 'B'],
        ['Peter', 'A'],
        ['Peter', 'C']
    ];

    function transformArray(arr)
    {
        let result = {};

        arr.forEach(function(item) {

            let name = item[0];

            let category = item[1];
    
            if (!result[name]) {
                result[name] = {};
            }
    
            if (!result[name][category]) {
                result[name][category] = 1;
            } else {
                result[name][category]++;
            }
        });
    
        return result;
    }

    console.log(transformArray(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group by both values and map the count.

```js
const
    data = [['Jack', 'A'], ['Jack', 'A'], ['Sara', 'A'], ['Jack', 'B'], ['Peter', 'B'], ['Sara', 'C'], ['Sara', 'B'], ['Sara', 'A'], ['Sara', 'B'], ['Peter', 'B'], ['Peter', 'A'], ['Peter', 'C']],
    result = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(data, a => a.join('|')))
        .map(a => [...a[0], a.length]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve `value-based` equivalence across arrays and count the occurrences of each equivalence class, you can utilize the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier/) library.

Simply add your data into a `Classifier`:

```
import { Classifier } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/Classifier.js";

const 
    classifier = new Classifier()
        .letAll(data);

assert.equal(classifier.n(['Jack', 'A']), 2)
```

The method `n(item)` counts the number of occurrences of each item.
Moreover, your data are intrinsically sorted (please, refer to the online documentation for an explanation).

The library extends beyond conventional `value-based` equivalence among objects. It accommodates `comparator-based` and `representation-based` equivalences, offering a broader spectrum of functionalities within its framework. For instance, while enumerating each equivalence class might not be particularly useful in scenarios of `value-based` equivalence, it becomes crucial in `representation-based` equivalences.